# How to use ACRA and also set UncaughtExceptionHandler?

Tags: android, exception, crash, acra

In my application, i want to set the uncaught exception handler so that i can do stuff in the event that of an unforseen crash. (i want to do stuff like close out sockets, clear notification...etc.)

`Thread.currentThread().setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(sDefaultThreadHandler);`

where

```
private static UncaughtExceptionHandler sDefaultThreadHandler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        // i want ACRA to log here, then clear notifications, close out connections, cancel asynctasks...etc.

        // DO NOT REMOVE or else your app will hang when there is a crash.
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(10);
    }
};
```

the problem is, i want ACRA to also report before the process exits. how do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Oh wait, nvm. i found out that ACRA uses the default exception handler (according to https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/acra/ErrorReporter.java#L201), so that means that if your own thread has a thread exception handler, that will be used first.

`Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(mYourOwnThreadHandler);`

and if you really need to use ACRA, then inside the `uncaughtException()` method that you override, just delegate it upwards by calling `Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(thread, ex);`

Comment: IMHO you have to store the default UEH in onCreate() defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(); and call it in the handler with defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex); Calling Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(thread, ex); from the handler will cause a loop.