# Android Intercept Unhandled Exceptions

Tags: java, android, exception

So I want to intercept the unhandled exceptions and I am doing this by:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

            //MY CUSTOM CODE TO SEND LOGS
            System.exit(2);

        }

    });
```

Is there anyway I can execute my custom code and then resume normal way it handles these exceptions? I believe I am getting some hanging issues since `System.exit` doesn't seem to be working reliably.

Comment: Call `Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(thread, ex)` to get the default behavior, if that's what you mean. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23124561/115145.

Comment: @CommonsWare so I can basically do my own logic and then call `Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(thread, ex)` in the above code I posted?

Comment: Yes. That will trigger the normal error dialog and such that is supplied by Android and augmented by the Play Store (or other distribution channels on other devices).

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried it and it doesn't seem to automatically kill the application. I just have it hanging.

Comment: If you remove your `UncaughtExceptionHandler` entirely, what happens?

Comment: That wont work @CommonsWare because when you do it at that point, the method will infinitely call itself, because it was set as the default exception handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the default handler first. Then intercept and send the error too the handler. System.exit... is a bad idea.

So first you create a custom exceptionhandler like you did:

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

    public CustomExceptionHandler(Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH) {
            this.defaultUEH = defaultUEH;
    }
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(ex);
        String time = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
        String message = ex.getMessage();

        // send logs...

        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }
}
```

So basically in your onCreate method (best used in a custom Application class to have it fall all parts) set the default exception handler if not already set (check not needed in Application):

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

if (!(defaultUEH instanceof CustomExceptionHandler)) {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler(defaultUEH));
}
```

I wrote it [here](https://github.com/Ph1b/MaterialAudiobookPlayer/blob/v1.5.4-rc2/audiobook/src/main/java/de/ph1b/audiobook/utils/BaseApplication.java) (remove the BuildConfig.DEBUG check) implemented to directly start the email client. If there is no email client installed, you should catch the `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Comment: I see what you are doing. How does the `CustomExceptionHandler` get access to `defaultUEH`?

Comment: Either have the class inside your class, or use a constructor. Updated my answer.

Comment: Sounds good, I will give it a try and update the question once I do.